# search a text using xmlread in xml file

Tags: xml, matlab, search

I would like to search a text in xml file and check that it has the correct value
using Matlab.

I tried :

```
myFolder = 'folder1';
OutputFile = fullfile(myFolder ,'info.xml');
xmlNode = xmlread(OutputFile );
```

I would like to check that 'characteristic','color' options exists and that they have respectively the values : hybrid and red ?

info.xml content--------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Custom_project name="" val="True" name="file1" path="file:/C:/Users/Local/Temp/info.xml" version="1.0">
   <verif="true" name="values" path="file:/C:/Users/Temp/folder1">
      <optList name="values">
         <opt name="color">red</option>
         <opt name="police">calibri</option>
         <opt name="font">blue</option>
      </optList>
    </verif>
   <toto="myvalue" name="option1">
      <opt name="myvalue_1">32</option>
      <opt name="-total">All</option>
      <opt name="characteristic">hybrid</option>
   </toto>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `xmlread` is not required, this is one possible solution. Multiple definitions of the same XML options are not checked, so any matching option name - option value pair is counted as a match.

% function that uses `regexp` to find matching string in XMLdata.

```
function [IsMatch] = xmlmatch(XMLdata, Variable, Value)
IsMatch = ~isempty(regexp(XMLdata, [ '.*<opt\s*name="', Variable, '">', Value, '</option>.*' ]));
return
```

% open the file, get file ID

```
fid = fopen('info.xml');
```

% read the file contents (assume text file).

```
XMLdata = fscanf(fid, '%s');
```

% check the XMLdata's variables' values:

```
IsColorRed = xmlmatch(XMLdata, 'color', 'red');
IsColorRed =
    1

IsColorBlue = xmlmatch(XMLdata, 'color', 'blue');
IsColorBlue =
    0

IsCharacteristicHybrid = xmlmatch(XMLdata, 'characteristic', 'hybrid');
IsCharacteristicHybrid =
    1

IsCharacteristicHybr = xmlmatch(XMLdata, 'characteristic', 'hybr');
IsCharacteristicHybr =
    0
```

% close the file.

```
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: hello nrz
, thank you , this is to check values and how to also check that the option exist ?

Comment: @lola You're welcome. Yes, this checks the existence of the option given in `Variable` and that it has the correct value given in `Value`. Acturally it's nothing more than pattern matching using regular expressions with `regexp` command, so if the XML variable given in `Variable` does not exist, there is no matching pattern in `XMLdata`, and so `IsMatch` will be 0. For more info on MATLAB's regular expressions, I recommend to check out [MATLAB documentation about regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html).

Comment: thanks nrz
I mean if I can check that all xml variables are available in the info.xml ?

Comment: @lola Yes, if XML variables you use follow the format: `'<opt\s*name="',Variable,'">',Value,'</option>'`  ... (without ' ,). In which `\s*` refers to any amount of whitespace characters (spaces or tabs), `Variable` refers to the XML option, and `Value` refers to the option's value. `'.*'` in the beginng and end of the regular expression means "any number of any characters", which basically allows the pattern to be located anywhere in the `XMLdata`. If you are only interested in checking the existence of an XML option, use `'.*'` as `Value`: `IsColorDefined = xmlmatch(XMLdata, 'color', '.*');`

Comment: `xmlread` outputs Document Object Model nodes (DOMnodes), not regular text vectors as `fscanf` does. Unfortunately I haven't used `xmlread` nor any other command that uses DOMnode objects. You could check out `xmlread` and "What Is an XML Document Object Model (DOM)" documentation in MATLAB or in web, and try to implement some basic DOMnode handling code (like creating some kind of basic "Hello World!" `.html` webpage using DOMnode commands), and if that doesn't work out the way you wanted to, you could post a question eg. about handling DOMnode objects in MATLAB.