# Modify XML fields in MATLAB

Tags: xml, matlab, search, xml-parsing

I have an XML text data of a file in [MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177241/search-a-text-using-xmlread-in-xml-file),in which I need to access the particular fields such as font-family,font-size etc.
I need to check that data for particular type (say font-family:Calibri;)and save present value to a variable. Then modify that particular field(say font-family:Calibri to some new font-family for eg;times New roman).
How to access that particular field in XML file, save present value and modify. I found this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177241/search-a-text-using-xmlread-in-xml-file) but I could not solve my problem

```
   <text xml:space="preserve" style="font-size:24px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-       weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri" x="3.0304575" y="32.847713" id="text3117" sodipodi:linespacing="125%" transform="translate(0,1004.3622)">
   <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="tspan3119" x="3.0304575" y="32.847713">6-19h</tspan> 
   </text>
```

the text field is inside g which is inside the field svg

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't that other answer help you?

Comment: @darthbith I tried the following code to get the particular font, but I did not get. function [IsMatch] = xmlmatch(XMLdata, Variable, Value)

       IsMatch = ~isempty(regexp(XMLdata, [ '.*<text\s*font-   family:="', Variable, '">', Value, '</text>.*' ]));    

       return